# Error checking for 2D array, Battleship game

Tags: java, arrays, string

Evening/morning lads!
I'm having an issue with a little program that I'm working for a school project. The goal was to create a player vs. pc battleship program with 2D arrays. The user should be limited to 15/10/5 torpedoes/. The program runs just fine (even better than I expected), but unfortunately, when the user attempts to shoot at the same spot twice it will count that torpedo. Also, if the user will try to shoot the same "square" twice where the ship is it will count that "hit", meaning that you can just win by shooting at that square.

I tried fixing it by making a statement in *public static int fire* method:

`if(board[row-1][col-1].equals("X") || board[row-1][col-1].equals("M")
{
   torpedoes++;
}`

didn't work, unfortunately... here is the whole method:

```
    public static int fire(String[][] board, int hits, int torpedoes)
   {
      int row = 0, col = 0;
      System.out.println("You have " + torpedoes + " torpedoes left...");
      System.out.println("Select a row to fire in: ");
      row = in.nextInt();
      while(row > 8 || row < 1)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter a valid row (1 - 8) and try again...");
         row = in.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("Select a column to fire in: ");
      col = in.nextInt();
      while(col > 8 || col < 1)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter a valid column (1 - 8) and try again...");
         col = in.nextInt();
      }

      if(board[row-1][col-1].equals("S"))
      {
         hits++;
         System.out.println("Hit!");
         board[row-1][col-1] = "X";
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Miss!");
         board[row-1][col-1] = "M";
      }
      return hits;
   }
```

and the complete program if it helps someone to look at the whole thing:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BattleshipsButBetter
{
   static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static boolean hideShip = true; //Make the ship hidden or not for testing
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      do
      {
         System.out.println("Privet, comrade.");
         System.out.println("Welcome to modified battleship program!");


         String[][] board = new String[8][8];
         createBoard(board);
         createShip(board, 4);

         int torpedoes = 0;
         int hits = 0;
         int difficulty = getDifficulty();

            if(difficulty == 1)
            {
               torpedoes = 15;
            }
            else if(difficulty == 2)
            {
               torpedoes = 10;
            }
            else
            {
               torpedoes = 5;
            }

         System.out.println("You have only " + torpedoes + " torpedoes to sink the ship... good luck!");

         while(torpedoes > 0 && hits < 4)
         {
            showBoard(board);
            hits = fire(board, hits, torpedoes);
            torpedoes--;
         }
         results(hits, torpedoes);  
      }while(repeat());
   }

   public static int getDifficulty()
   {
      System.out.println("Select a difficulty: \n 1. Normal \n 2. Hard \n 3 or any other number = impossible!");
      return in.nextInt();
   }

   public static void createBoard(String[][] board)
   {
      for(int x = 0; x < board.length; x++)
         for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++)
            board[x][y] = "~";
   }

   public static void showBoard(String[][] board)
   {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");
      for(int x = 0; x < board.length; x++)
      {
         if(hideShip == false)
         {
            System.out.print(x + 1);
            for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++)
            {
               System.out.print(" " + board[x][y]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.print(x + 1);
            for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++)
            {
               if(board[x][y].equals("S"))
               {
                  System.out.print(" " + "~");
               }
               else
               {
                  System.out.print(" " + board[x][y]);
               }
            }
            System.out.println("");
         }
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static void createShip(String[][] board, int size)
   {
      if(Math.random() < 0.5)
      {
         int col = (int)(Math.random()*5);
         int row = (int)(Math.random()*7);
         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
            board[row][col+i] = "S";
         }
      }
      else
      {
         int col = (int)(Math.random()*7);
         int row = (int)(Math.random()*5);
         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
            board[row+i][col] = "S";
         }
      }
   }

   public static int fire(String[][] board, int hits, int torpedoes)
   {
      int row = 0, col = 0;
      System.out.println("You have " + torpedoes + " torpedoes left...");
      System.out.println("Select a row to fire in: ");
      row = in.nextInt();
      while(row > 8 || row < 1)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter a valid row (1 - 8) and try again...");
         row = in.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("Select a column to fire in: ");
      col = in.nextInt();
      while(col > 8 || col < 1)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter a valid column (1 - 8) and try again...");
         col = in.nextInt();
      }

      if(board[row-1][col-1].equals("S"))
      {
         hits++;
         System.out.println("Hit!");
         board[row-1][col-1] = "X";
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Miss!");
         board[row-1][col-1] = "M";
      }
      return hits;
   }

   public static void results(int hits, int torpedoes)
   {
      if(hits < 4)
         System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't sink the ship :(");
      if(torpedoes < 1)
         System.out.println("You have lost all of your torpedoes!");
      else
         if(hits >= 4)
         {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, comrade, you sank the ship. GG WP!");
         }
   }

   public static boolean repeat()
   {
      int repeat;
      System.out.println();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      do
      {
         System.out.println("Would you like to play again? 1. YES, 2. NO");
         repeat = in.nextInt();
         if(repeat < 1 || repeat > 2)
         {
            System.out.println(repeat + " is not a valid entry.");
         }
      }
      while(repeat < 1 || repeat > 2);
      System.out.println();
      return repeat == 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to fixing the game was correct, but there was a problem: Integers in Java are passed by value, therefore any modification of
   integer `torpedoes` within `fire` method had no effect outside it.

To make it work, I've added a Static class `FireResult` to a program. This class stores `hits` and `torpedoes` count resulting from the invocation of `fire` method:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BattleshipsButBetter {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static boolean hideShip = true; //Make the ship hidden or not for testing
    private static FireResult fr = new FireResult();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Privet, comrade.");
            System.out.println("Welcome to modified battleship program!");


            String[][] board = new String[8][8];
            createBoard(board);
            createShip(board, 4);

            int torpedoes = 0;
            int hits = 0;
            int difficulty = getDifficulty();

            if(difficulty == 1)
            {
                torpedoes = 15;
            }
            else if(difficulty == 2)
            {
                torpedoes = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                torpedoes = 5;
            }

            System.out.println("You have only " + torpedoes + " torpedoes to sink the ship... good luck!");

            while(torpedoes > 0 && hits < 4)
            {
                showBoard(board);
                fire(board, hits, torpedoes);
                // Get results from FireResult static class
                hits = fr.hits;
                torpedoes = fr.torpedoes;

                // Original logic continues
                torpedoes--;
            }
            results(hits, torpedoes);
        }while(repeat());
    }

    public static int getDifficulty()
    {
        System.out.println("Select a difficulty: \n 1. Normal \n 2. Hard \n 3 or any other number = impossible!");
        return in.nextInt();
    }

    public static void createBoard(String[][] board)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < board.length; x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++)
                board[x][y] = "~";
    }

    public static void showBoard(String[][] board)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8");
        for(int x = 0; x < board.length; x++)
        {
            if(hideShip == false)
            {
                System.out.print(x + 1);
                for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + board[x][y]);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(x + 1);
                for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++)
                {
                    if(board[x][y].equals("S"))
                    {
                        System.out.print(" " + "~");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print(" " + board[x][y]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void createShip(String[][] board, int size)
    {
        if(Math.random() < 0.5)
        {
            int col = (int)(Math.random()*5);
            int row = (int)(Math.random()*7);
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                board[row][col+i] = "S";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int col = (int)(Math.random()*7);
            int row = (int)(Math.random()*5);
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                board[row+i][col] = "S";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void fire(String[][] board, int hits, int torpedoes)
    {
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        System.out.println("You have " + torpedoes + " torpedoes left...");
        System.out.println("Select a row to fire in: ");
        row = in.nextInt();
        while(row > 8 || row < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid row (1 - 8) and try again...");
            row = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Select a column to fire in: ");
        col = in.nextInt();
        while(col > 8 || col < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid column (1 - 8) and try again...");
            col = in.nextInt();
        }

        if(board[row-1][col-1].equals("X") || board[row-1][col-1].equals("M"))
        {
            torpedoes++;
        }
        else if(board[row-1][col-1].equals("S"))
        {
            hits++;
            System.out.println("Hit!");
            board[row-1][col-1] = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Miss!");
            board[row-1][col-1] = "M";
        }

        fr.hits = hits;
        fr.torpedoes = torpedoes;
    }

    public static void results(int hits, int torpedoes)
    {
        if(hits < 4)
            System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't sink the ship :(");
        if(torpedoes < 1)
            System.out.println("You have lost all of your torpedoes!");
        else
        if(hits >= 4)
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, comrade, you sank the ship. GG WP!");
        }
    }

    public static boolean repeat()
    {
        int repeat;
        System.out.println();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? 1. YES, 2. NO");
            repeat = in.nextInt();
            if(repeat < 1 || repeat > 2)
            {
                System.out.println(repeat + " is not a valid entry.");
            }
        }
        while(repeat < 1 || repeat > 2);
        System.out.println();
        return repeat == 1;
    }

    public static class FireResult {
        int hits;
        int torpedoes;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ;)